# Android : How to implement a listener for softkey press

Tags: android

I want to measure the time taken between two soft key press. I tried to implement the KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener, but it's not working. How to access the resource id for the inbuilt soft keyboard?

```
keyboardView = (KeyBoardView) findViewByID(R.id. ??) 


keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(kList);

KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener kList = new KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
         Log.d("Hello", "1");
     }

     @Override
     public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
         Log.d("Hello", "2");
     }

     @Override
     public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
         Log.d("Hello", "3");
     }

     @Override
     public void onText(CharSequence text) {
         Log.d("Hello", "4");
     }
```

If all of this is wrong, please tell me how to implement a KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener.

Comment: what you are trying to do will work with custom keyboards

Comment: you must implement your own custom keyboard..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the Keyboard directly. You will have to implement your own Keyboard to measure accurate timing between key-presses. Alternatively, create an EditText and disable auto completion. Then measure the time between the text changes.